# WPF: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on WPF application.

I want to display my treeview only when I select item from combobox.

Here is my combobox select property

```
    public string SelectedTransactionName
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTransactionWsName == value) return;
            this._selectedTransactionWsName = value;

            // InitializaMessageElement(value.WsMethodName, transactionTypes);
            InitializaMessageElement();

            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>IsTransactionNameSelected.ToString());
        }
        get
        {
            return this._selectedTransactionWsName;
        }

    }
```

Check trans name selected or not.

```
  public bool IsTransactionNameSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedTransactionWsName);
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <TreeView Margin="464,137,10,413" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding   MessageElements,  Mode=TwoWay}"   
                  SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged"  Visibility="    {Binding IsTransactionNameSelected,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                 SelectedValuePath="Id"
```

At  this.NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>IsTransactionNameSelected.ToString()); I am getting the error (Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type), my NotifyPropertyChanged takes a string

Comment: What's your specific question?  If it's about the title, could you point people to which line you're talking about.  You haven't provided complete code, so people have to guess at what might help you.  Sticking questions in code means they don't get noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NotifyPropertyChanged` expects a string, and you're passing it a delegate.  Try:

```
public string SelectedTransactionName
{
    set
    {
        if (_selectedTransactionWsName == value) return;
        this._selectedTransactionWsName = value;

        // InitializaMessageElement(value.WsMethodName, transactionTypes);
        InitializaMessageElement();

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTransactionName");
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("IsTransactionNameSelected");
    }

    get
    {
        return this._selectedTransactionWsName;
    }
}
```